# How do I successfully load matplotlib on Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to `import matplotlib`, here is how it looks.

when i click run, it shows me nothing but the whole code`import matplotlib`turns to grey. It happened every module I load in. I want to know is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm does this whith the import statements that are not used, so you can keep control of which modules the code is actually using. It will be normal again once you use it in your code.